# Automation ui test in docker

Tags: linux, jenkins, docker-compose, automation, webdriver-manager

I have a task to run a UI automated test in a container, and I need help.

docker, docker-compose, java, webdrivermanager, linux, Jenkins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhXmw.jpg)

Error: ProfileListTest > initializationError FAILED

```
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException at WebDriverManager.java:1760

    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException at ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.java:195

        Caused by: java.io.IOException at DomainSocket.java:63

            Caused by: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException at LinuxDomainSocket.java:-2
```

Test code:

```
static WebDriverManager wdm = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserInDocker().enableVnc().enableRecording();
@BeforeAll

public static void setUp(){

    // Настройки браузера

    wdm.create();      //add browserInDocker and change setup on create()

    Configuration.browser = "chrome";

    Configuration.browserSize = "1920x1080";

    Configuration.headless = true;                                  // для работы в контейнере "true" выставлять

    // Вход в систему

    open(BASE_URL);

    SelenideElement searchLogin = $(By.id("login"));

    searchLogin.setValue(LOGIN);

    SelenideElement searchPassword = $(By.id("password"));

    searchPassword.setValue(PASSWORD).pressEnter();

}


@AfterAll

public static void tearDown(){

    // Выход из системы (logout)

    open(BASE_URL);

    SelenideElement dropDownListProfile = $(By.linkText(LOGIN));

    dropDownListProfile.click();

    $(By.partialLinkText("Выход")).click();

    // Чистка куки и localStorage

    Selenide.clearBrowserCookies();

    Selenide.clearBrowserLocalStorage();

    // Откл драйвера

    wdm.quit();

}
```

}

I'm the only QA in the company, so I have no one else to ask for hel
p.

I just don't have idea what can trying

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is help:
chmod a+rw /var/run/docker.sock

For those who encounter build errors, here's a logging tip. Add the following to the test{} block in your gradle.build:

testLogging {
events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
exceptionFormat "full"
showStandardStreams = true // This sets the logging level to "debug"
}

This way, you'll be able to see which specific test is failing and get detailed logs for all stages of the build and execution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).